# React i18next return a fallback language

Tags: javascript, reactjs, i18next

I'm using i18next in my React app in this way to translate files:

**i18next.js (original)**

```
import i18next from 'i18next';
import XHR from 'i18next-xhr-backend';
import detector from 'i18next-browser-languagedetector';

window.userLang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;
i18next
    .use(detector)
    .use(XHR)
    .init({
        lng: window.userLang,
        fallbackLng: 'en',
        debug: true,
        interpolation: {
            escapeValue: false,
        },
    });

export default i18next;
```

Using the code above, I am able to successfully translate pages based on the user's browser data. If the language is not available, it falls back to English as intended.

However, I ran into some components which were not translated into the keys provided. They are set up in the following way in the menu component:

**Menu Component**

```
const projectArchives = i18next.t('LEFT_MENU.projectArchives');

export default {
    [KEY_ARCHIVE_MODEL]: {
        en: projectArchives,
        it: projectArchives,
    },
```

Output in browser:
`LEFT_MENU.projectArchives`

I changed my i18next.js file to have a variable (`var data =`) which would get the language from a string:

**i18next.js (Updated)**

```
import i18next from 'i18next';
import XHR from 'i18next-xhr-backend';
import detector from 'i18next-browser-languagedetector';

window.userLang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;

let language = window.userLang.split('-')[0];
var data = require(`../../public/locales/${language}/translation.json`); 
const FALLBACK_LOCALE = 'en';

i18next
    .use(detector)
    .use(XHR)
    .init({
        lng: window.userLang,
        fallbackLng: FALLBACK_LOCALE,
        debug: true,
        resources: {
            otherLanguages: FALLBACK_LOCALE,
            it: {
                translation: data,
            },
            en: {
                translation: data,
            },
        },
    });

export default i18next;
```

Now, the menu is able to display the translated keys but now, if a language is not available as in the original code, the following error is returned:

`Error: Cannot find module './fr/translation.json'.` 
because there is ofcourse there is not an available French translation file.

The error occurs because of the following line:

`` var data = require(`../../public/locales/${language}/translation.json`); ``

I've tried connecting the `FALLBACK_LOCALE` variable directly to the English translation file but this also failed.

`` var FALLBACK_LOCALE = require(`../../public/locales/en/translation.json`); ``

How can I force the fallback language or create a conditional for the expected behavior?

Answer (score 0):

```
import i18next from 'i18next';
import XHR from 'i18next-xhr-backend';
import detector from 'i18next-browser-languagedetector';

window.userLang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;

let language = window.userLang.split('-')[0];
const FALLBACK_LOCALE = 'en';

i18next
    .use(detector)
    .use(XHR)
    .init({
        lng: window.userLang,
        fallbackLng: FALLBACK_LOCALE,
        debug: true,
        resources: {
            otherLanguages: FALLBACK_LOCALE,
            it: {
                translation: require(`../../public/locales/it/translation.json`),
            },
            en: {
                translation: require(`../../public/locales/en/translation.json`),
            },
        },
    });

export default i18next;
```